# I need help getting the user to enter 10 currencies instead of 1

Tags: java, eclipse

I have got the code below that when the user Enters 1-5 from the keyboard it converts GBP to one of the selected currencies. At the moment it takes 1 user input and converts it, but I need it too take 10 user inputs and convert all 10 to the currency the user selects. I believe a for loop is needed something like

```
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
```

is needed. Can anyone help??

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        currency();
    }

    public static void currency(){
        int input;



        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("1. Euros");
        System.out.println("2. USD ");
        System.out.println("3. Yen");
        System.out.println("4. Rupees");
        System.out.println("5. Exit ?");

        input = keyboard.nextInt();

        if(input == 1){
            float XEUR = (float) 1.19;
            System.out.println("Enter 10 GBP values to be converted to EUR:");
            System.out.println("EUR: " + keyboard.nextFloat() * XEUR);

    }else if(input == 2){
            float XUSD = (float) 1.26;
            System.out.println("Enter 10 GBP values to be converted to USD:");
            System.out.println("USD: " + keyboard.nextFloat() * XUSD);

        } else if (input == 3){
            float XYEN = (float) 145.02;
            System.out.println("Enter 10 GBP values to be converted to Yen:");
            System.out.println("YEN: " + keyboard.nextFloat() * XYEN);

        }else if(input == 4){
                float XRUP = (float) 84.86;
                System.out.println("Enter 10 GBP values to be converted to Rupees:");
                System.out.println("USD: " + keyboard.nextFloat() * XRUP);
        }else if(input == 5){
                    System.out.println("Exiting");

      }
    }   
}
```

Comment: All ten inputs to a single currency?

Comment: yes, so the user would select 1,2,3,4 then it would ask the user to input 10 GBP to be converted to the selection they did at the start

Comment: You may want to simplify the code before extending it to multiple conversions: What doesn't change between the controlled block statements? Is there a way to have only one "copy"? Next, put that in a _loop_. (Oh, and please revise the title: those will be ten _amounts_, not currencies.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the inputs in array and process like this:

```
int input = keyboard.nextInt();
if (input < 1 || input > 5) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
    return;
}
if (input == 5) {
    System.out.println("Exiting");
    return;
}
float[] vals = new float[10];
for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter "+ (i+1) +" value");
    vals[i] = keyboard.nextFloat();
}

switch(input) {
    case 1:
        // process the vals in loop:
        for(int v : vals) {
            // do conversion here
        }
        break;
    // handle other cases
}
```